# Behavior of specific PDA for a certain input

Tags: complexity-theory, finite-automata, pushdown-automata

Suppose we're given the non-deterministic PDA shown below which reads from the alphabet $\sum = \lbrace a,b \rbrace$. How will this PDA behave if we pass it the string $ba$? We read $b$ first and push $b$ to the stack, but when we read $a$ I get confused. My assumption is that we fork into two new branches - one in which $b$ was popped and one in which $a$ was pushed. Is this correct? If not, can you tell me where I go wrong?

Thank you very much!

[image]

Comment: You're correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This PDA is non deterministic. So just like in non-deterministic Finite State Machines you fork.

A string is only accepted by the PDA if one of the forks ends in an accepting state.